# update sql table from two tables Using a single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want to update a table column by taking i/p from two tables in a single query.

This is what i have tried.

```
   $query="UPDATE all_stores a
inner join i_v i on
    a.id = i.child_id
set a.qty = (a.qty-i.qty)";
```

But this is not updating the table.

Where Table-all_stores is:

```
   id-    name         qty -           dec_qty
    1      a1          68                0
    2      b2          32                0
    3      c3          12                0
    4      d4          43                0
```

And table-i_v is:

```
    id-    name        qty -          child_id
    1      a1          12               1
    2      a2          32               2
    3      a1          11               1
    4      a1          23               1
```

Comment: An `update` query does not "fetch" results.  It changes data in the table.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the number rows that your statement updated : [mysqli affected rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) or [PDO row count](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand correctly , you want to do this :

```
UPDATE all_stores a
set a.qty = (a.qty-(select sum(qty) from i_v i where a.id = i.id))
```

Comment: Yes, But this is also not working. No update to the database!

Comment: @himanshutomar , actually you could make it much simpler, see updated answer , that should work

Comment: This is working,thanks
But,
It is updating the field not matching the where clause to '0'.
Pl assist.

Comment: I can’t understand what you trying to say

Comment: did you understand my query now?

Comment: Thank you @eshirvana it worked after i made a blank entry to the table.